# Twilio Synch token in ColdFusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, twilio, twilio-api

ColdFusion being as obscure as it is, Twilio doesn't have any SDKs for it. I'm trying to give Synch a go; I'm not getting the JSON request for the access token correct. Trying to mimic what is done by their node.js example [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/identity-and-access-tokens), I thought I could just output the JSON to the page on token.cfm:

```
    {
        "identity":"#Username#",
        "token":["#AccountSID#","#APPSID#","#SECRET#"]
    }
```

This is called from index.cfm:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"  ></script> 
<script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/0.5.7/twilio-sync.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function fetchAccessToken(handler) {
      // We use jQuery to make an Ajax request to our server to retrieve our 
      // Access Token
      $.getJSON('token.cfm', function(data) {
          // The data sent back from the server should contain a long string, which
          // is the token you'll need to initialize the SDK. This string is in a format
          // called JWT (JSON Web Token) - more at http://jwt.io
          console.log(data.token);

          // Since the starter app doesn't implement authentication, the server sends
          // back a randomly generated username for the current client, which is how
          // they will be identified while sending messages. If your app has a login
          // system, you should use the e-mail address or username that uniquely identifies
          // a user instead.
          console.log(data.identity);

          handler(data);
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        fetchAccessToken(initializeSync);

        function initializeSync(tokenResponse) {
          var syncClient = new Twilio.Sync.Client(tokenResponse.token);

          // Use syncClient here
        }
    });

</script>
```

The response I receive is

```
{code: 400, message: "Unable to process JSON"}
code:
400
message:
"Unable to process JSON"
```

Can I accomplish this? Or, alternately, can the token be built by JavaScript alone?

Comment: Assuming the actual content of the JSON is correct, off the top of my head, I know CF has an option to prefix JSON responses with a string (defaults to `//` if it's enabled I believe). It may be worth making sure that is off in your CF settings.

Comment: I'm not sure the json content is actually correct. I'm not 100% sure what it is looking for or where to find it. Part of the node is `// Create a "grant" identifying the Sync service instance for this app.
    var syncGrant = new SyncGrant({
        serviceSid: process.env.TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID,
    });` - I'm not sure what this does.

Comment: @CollinD I did double check the prefix option, it's off.

Comment: At what point in the code are you getting the error message?

Comment: When trying to pass the token to twilio at `var syncClient = new Twilio.Sync.Client(tokenResponse.token);`, the error is the response I receive.

Comment: ok. I added some Twilio tags to your question. Hopefully someone with more experience can help out.

Comment: Silly that I missed those tags...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JS is a very roundabout way of writing this:

```
$(function() {
    $.get('token.cfm').done(function (response) {
        var syncClient = new Twilio.Sync.Client(response.token);
        // ... use syncClient here
    });
});
```

but this still requires that the response is actually parseable as JSON.

If your CFM page just contains this:

```
<cfoutput>
{
    "identity":"#Username#",
    "token":["#AccountSID#","#APPSID#","#SECRET#"]
}
</cfoutput>
```

then this almost certainly produces syntactically wrong JSON. Don't do that.

JSON is to be produced from a data structure and a serialization function, that's no different in ColdFusion than in any other language.

```
<cfset AccountSID = "...">
<cfset APPSID  = "...">
<cfset SECRET = "...">

<cfset tokenData = {
    "identity" = Username,
    "token" = [AccountSID, APPSID, SECRET]
}>

<cfcontent type="application/json"><cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(tokenData)#</cfoutput>
```

There are other, nicer ways of creating JSON responses, most prominently CF components with functions annotated with the "json" `returnformat`, but doing it manually like above is enough for a one-off.

Comment: Okay that is quite helpful, I couldn't find the proper way to output JSON in coldfusion. This gets me a step closer. the error now is `Uncaught Error: Sync library needs a valid Twilio token to be passed
    at new t (twilio-sync.min.js:99)` So now I just need to know what a valid twilio token looks like.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that. Other than going through the Twilio documentation while knowing even less about it than you do. ;)

Comment: Speaking of which, usable and fast ColdFusion documentation is here: https://cfdocs.org/

Comment: On the off chance anyone comes across this with the same problem, the tokens need to be encoded. I'm using the library found here to encode them in coldfusion. `https://github.com/mattiLeBlanc/cfml8-jwt `

Comment: Ah, I suppose you are using CF 10 or higher, so a big part of that CFC would be redundant by now. But if it works you can of course still use it.

Comment: Also, if the consumer is case sensitive watch out for CF's tendency to default structure key names to upper case. One way to prevent that is to quote the key names, ie `<cfset tokenData = {"identity" = "...",    "token" = []}>`

Comment: Thanks @Leigh; I was unsure about that part, as I have no way to test right now, but I had a suspicion that CF would be upper-casing the keys. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Yes, as usual CF likes to upper case everything ;-) https://trycf.com/gist/e5e13b1cfa5f289841de36c5ea2c3106/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: I'll try t o remember trycf.com. Handy site, even though almost nobody asks CF-questions anymore...